Error '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute "x"
Esto haciendo una app, en la cual tengo 3 archivos los cuales pueden esta implicados, un archivo manager que lo inicio asi
class principalscreen(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self) :
        super().__init__() # inicializamos el objeto
        self.logo = util_img.leer_imagen("./imagenes/logo.png", (560,136))
        self.perfil = util_img.leer_imagen("./imagenes/perfil.png", (100,100))
        self.config_window()
        Home.frames(self)
        Home.topbar_controls(self)
        Home.sidebar_menu_controls(self)

y tengo otro archivo que se llama screens, que es para poner las pantallas de la aplicación (las pantallas las divido por clases).
El tema que en uno de los frames de mi pantalla en el que quiero agregar unas funciones me tira este error:
'_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'toggle_panel'

o sino:
'_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'config_button_menu'

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Este es el código:
from config import *
import tkinter as tk
from formularios.Manager import *

class Home (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.frames()
        self.topbar_controls()
        self.sidebar_menu_controls()
        
    
    def frames(self):
        self.top_bar = tk.Frame(
            self,
            bg = COLOR_BARRA_SUPERIOR, 
            height = 50 )
        self.top_bar.pack(
                side=tk.TOP,
                fill = 'both'
            )
        
        self.side_menu = tk.Frame(
            self,
            bg = COLOR_MENU_LATERAL, 
            width = 150 )
        self.side_menu.pack(
                side=tk.LEFT,
                fill = 'both',
                expand = False
            )
        
        self.principal_body = tk.Frame(
            self,
            bg = COLOR_CUERPO_PRINCIPAL
            )
        self.principal_body.pack(
                side=tk.RIGHT,
                fill = 'both',
                expand = True
            )

    def topbar_controls (self):
        font_awesome = font.Font(family='FontAwesome', size=12) 
        
        self.labelTitle = tk.Label(self.top_bar, text="LABS")
        self.labelTitle.config(fg = "#fff", 
                            font = ("Roboto", 15),
                                bg = COLOR_BARRA_SUPERIOR,
                                pady = 10,
                                width = 16 )
        self.labelTitle.pack(side = tk.LEFT,fill = "both")
    
        self.buttonmenu = tk.Button (self.top_bar,
                                    text="\uf0c9",
                                    font = font_awesome,
                                    bd = 0,    
                                    bg = COLOR_BARRA_SUPERIOR,
                                    fg = "white", 
                                    command=self.toggle_panel)
        self.buttonmenu.pack(side = tk.LEFT) 
        
        self.bind_hover_events(self, self.buttonmenu)
        
        
        self.labelTitle = tk.Label(self.top_bar, text="onir.valiente@gmail.com")
        self.labelTitle.config(fg = "#fff", 
                            font = ("Roboto", 10),
                                bg = COLOR_BARRA_SUPERIOR,
                                padx = 10,
                                width = 20 )
        self.labelTitle.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)

    def sidebar_menu_controls (self):
        width_menu = 20
        heigth_menu = 2
        font_awesome = font.Font(family='FontAwesome', size=15)
        #imagenes como etiquetas
        self.labelperfil = tk.Label(
            self.side_menu, 
            image = self.perfil,    #Self.perfil, constante definida en el manager
            bg = COLOR_MENU_LATERAL)
        self.labelperfil.pack(side = tk.TOP,
                            pady = 10)
        
        #buttos for the menu
        self.buttondashboard = tk.Button(self.side_menu)
        self.buttonbilling = tk.Button(self.side_menu)
        self.buttonemployeds = tk.Button(self.side_menu)
        self.buttoncustomers = tk.Button(self.side_menu)
        self.buttonstock = tk.Button(self.side_menu)
        self.buttonsettings = tk.Button(self.side_menu)

        buttons_info = [
            ("Dashboard", "\uf109", self.buttondashboard),
            ("Punto de Venta", "\uf015", self.buttonbilling),
            ("Empleados", "\uf007", self.buttonemployeds),
            ("Clientes", "\uf007", self.buttoncustomers),
            ("Stock", "\uf129", self.buttonstock),
            ("Configutacion", "\uf013", self.buttonsettings)
        ]

        for text, icon, button in buttons_info:
            config_button_menu(self, button, text, icon, font_awesome, width_menu, heigth_menu)

        def toggle_panel(self):
            # Alterna la visibilidad del menú lateral
            if self.side_menu.winfo_ismapped(): # Esta función pregunta si está visible
                self.side_menu.pack_forget() # Si está visible, lo ocultamos
            else:
                self.side_menu.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill='y') # Si no está visible, lo mostramos


        def config_button_menu(self, button, text, icon, font_awesome, width_menu, height_menu):
                button.config(text = f"  {icon}   {text}",
                            anchor = "w",
                            font = font_awesome,
                            bd = 0,
                            bg = COLOR_MENU_LATERAL,
                            fg = "white",
                            width = width_menu,
                            height= height_menu)
                button.pack(side = tk.TOP)    
                bind_hover_events(self, button)

        def bind_hover_events (self, button):
            button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event:  on_enter(event, button))
            button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event:  on_leave(event, button))

        def on_enter(event, button): # aca indicamos cuando tenemos el mouse encima de que color cambia
            button.config (bg = COLOR_MENU_CURSOR_ENCIMA, fg = "white")

        def on_leave(event, button):# aca indicamos cuando tenemos el mouse no esta encima que se mantenga del mismo color
            button.config (bg = COLOR_MENU_LATERAL, fg = "white")

Le pedí ayuda a chat gpt y a copilot, pero no me dan la solución. Encontré una solución para que el config_butto_menu funcione, y es declarándolo fuera de la clase, pero quiero poder declararlo dentro de la clase así no me queda un smell code.
